# Xero PHP Oauth in Laravel throws 401 AuthenticationUnsuccessful when updating contacts

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, guzzle, xero-api

I am trying to update Xero contacts, which is part of the invoice in Laravel. I am using `Xero-php-oauth2`.  I have tried

```
$xero = resolve(AccountingApi::class);
$invoice = new Invoice();
$invoice->setLineItems($lineItems);
$result = $xero->updateInvoice($tenantId, $invoice_id, $invoice);
$contactId = $result->getInvoices()[0]['contact']['contact_id'];
$contact = $this->newContact();
$contact->setContactId($contactId);
//$tenantId, $contactid, and $contact are correct
$xero->updateContact($tenantId, $contactId, $contact);
```

The request I am trying to send is like following, but the response returns 401 `AuthenticationUnsuccessful`

```
Request {#1160 ▼
  -method: "POST"
  -requestTarget: null
  -uri: Uri {#1212 ▼
    -scheme: "https"
    -userInfo: ""
    -host: "api.xero.com"
    -port: null
    -path: "/api.xro/2.0/Contacts/134ab308-7d07-4c2d-a770-c01325947ede"
    -query: ""
    -fragment: ""
  }
  -headers: array:6 [▼
    "Host" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "api.xero.com"
    ]
    "User-Agent" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "[xero-php-oauth2 (2.11.0)]"
    ]
    "xero-tenant-id" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "TENANT_ID_HERE"
    ]
    "Accept" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "application/json"
    ]
    "Content-Type" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "application/json"
    ]
    "Authorization" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "Bearer BEARER_TOKEN_HERE"
    ]
  ]
  -headerNames: array:6 [▶]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: Stream {#1217 ▼
    -stream: stream resource @755 ▼
      wrapper_type: "PHP"
      stream_type: "TEMP"
      mode: "w+b"
      unread_bytes: 0
      seekable: true
      uri: "php://temp"
      options: []
    }
    -size: null
    -seekable: true
    -readable: true
    -writable: true
    -uri: "php://temp"
    -customMetadata: []
  }
}
```

`xero-php-oauth2` sends request along with following options to GuzzleHttp\Client, and It seems to throw error at `AccountingAPI@updateContactWithHttpInfo()` in following line

```
$response = $this->client->send($request, $options);`
```

I also tried to add `accounting.contacts` scope before calling  but it does not work.

```
$options = ['scope' => ['openid email profile offline_access accounting.settings accounting.transactions accounting.contacts accounting.journals.read accounting.reports.read accounting.attachments']];
```

Error message

```
[401] Client error: `POST https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Contacts/134ab308-7d07-4c2d-a770-c01325947ede` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"Type":null,"Title":"Unauthorized","Status":401,"Detail":"AuthenticationUnsuccessful","Instance":"94b725d8-435b-4a98-be (truncated...)
```

It is working when I create or update invoices with almost identical request. Even identical bearer token. Also creating new contact if I pass that with new invoice. But not updating already existing contact. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your access token might have expired since it lasts for only 30 mins.

Comment: I think access token is not expired as I run those on few seconds interval.

Comment: Ok, have you connected to xero client accounts to your app with different logins? How do you manage access token refreshes across multiple connections?

Comment: I think the AccountingAPI manages access token. `$headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' . $this->config->getAccessToken();` with our clientId and Client_secret in env. I have not connected to different logins, but the access tokens renew after they expire.

Comment: I have updated invoice then tried to update contacts afterwards. And both gets the same access tokens. Do access token need to be refreshed in between?

Comment: I am not sure if that method renews if the token expired. Regardless, 401 has to do something with the token. If it were something with the scope, Xero would have raised 403 forbidden error. Are you able to reproduce this on every refresh? Beware that a new refresh token is also generated each time. You might want to update that as well.

Comment: Yes, It does throw the same error on every refresh.

Comment: It is hard to debug without the setup on my machine. If you change the order of updates, does it cause the same problem?

Comment: Btw, you need to have all the required scopes in place already. You can't dynamically update scopes between API calls.

Comment: I get the contact Id from the first request, which is required for the update so order cannot be changed. I will try to set it static and test if it works by changing order. Will also test if it works with another account. And I also have required scope in the xero config file. I was just wondering if it is working correctly, so changed to test if it works.

Comment: I tried to connect to another account, then reconnect back to same account as per your suggestion. In the process, I found out that we get the token with given scope only when we connect at the first. other time they use older token and only renew refresh token. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the 401 response: `"Title":"Unauthorized"`. You're not unauthenticated, you're unauthorised.

From [the docs](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/scopes):

> When your app is requesting authorisation from a user it will need to ask for a set of scopes. These scopes will be displayed to the user and describe what data your app will be able to access.

You supply the relevant scopes [when requesting authentication with OAuth](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/auth-flow).

Your OAuth request (i.e. when you request authentication from the user) will be missing the [`accounts.contacts`](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/scopes#accounting-api) scope. Add it, and you should be able to successfully call those API endpoints.

Comment: I had accounts.contacts in my scopes list. But it would not take this scope until I disconnect it from xero and reconnected again. It was taking earlier scope. Anyway thanks

Comment: Yeah, the issue (as I laid out in my answer) is that the scopes need to be requested with the OAuth request. For obvious reasons, you can't use scopes the user hasn't authorised, so you can't change the scopes in your code after you've performed the OAuth request and expect to be able to access them.